# Error importing hashlib with python 2.7 but not with 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, solaris, solaris-10, hashlib

I'm on Solaris 10 (x86).

Until now, I was using python2.6. Today, I installed python2.7 and I have a weird error occuring when importing hashlib on 2.7, but not on 2.6:

Python 2.6:

```
root@myserver [PROD] # python2.6 -c "import hashlib"
root@myserver [PROD] #
```

Python 2.7:

```
root@myserver [PROD] # python2.7 -c "import hashlib"
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
```

I don't understand why I have this error since I'm trying the import **ON THE SAME MACHINE**.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Perhaps because your hashlib version is for Python 2.6 only? Which version are you on?

Comment: @alKid `hashlib` is a built-in module since Python 2.5

Comment: Also, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433108/unsupported-hash-type-when-installing-plone

Comment: Not really a duplicate, since my question is more generic.

I don't understand the error: if it's related to OpenSSL, I should have the same error for the 2 versions of python.

Why would it work for 2.6 and not for 2.7 with **the same openssl**?

Comment: run `python2.7 -v -c "import hashlib"` to see the list of what it is trying and failing to import.  `ldd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/_hashlibmodule.so` tells you what?.  i _suspect_ it is failing to load that due to how your locally compiled python2.7 was linked...

Comment: @gps The `ldd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/_hashlibmodule.so` returns a `cannot open file: No such file or directory` error.

The output of the first command is here: (http://pastebin.com/wbd1qAtv)

Thank you for your help! ;)

Comment: @gps I found the _hashlib.so file in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so`.

I launched the ldd command on it and here's the result (in next comment).

Comment: The ldd result:

`libssl.so.1.0.0 =>(file not found)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 =>(file not found)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 =>/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
libsocket.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libsocket.so.1
libnsl.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
librt.so.1 =>/usr/lib/librt.so.1
libdl.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libdl.so.1
libm.so.2 =>/usr/lib/libm.so.2
libc.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libc.so.1
libmp.so.2 =>/usr/lib/libmp.so.2
libmd.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libmd.so.1
libscf.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libscf.so.1
libaio.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libaio.so.1
libdoor.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libdoor.so.1
libuutil.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libuutil.so.1
libgen.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libgen.so.1`

Comment: So it seems that the files `libssl.so.1.0.0` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` are not "linked" correctly to the library.

I did the same with python2.6 and found links to openssl_0.9.8 librairies.

Comment: The python2.7 packages is dependent to the libssl1_0_0 (openssl_1.0 runtime librairies).

I installed it, and reinstalled python2.7, but the `libssl.so.1.0.0`and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` files still appears as `(file not found)` in the `ldd` command output.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The python2.7 package is dependent to the `libssl1_0_0` package (openssl_1.0 runtime librairies).

I installed it, and added the `/usr/local/ssl/lib` directory in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environnent variable.

And now it works perfectly! :)

Comment: whats the command to do /usr/local/ssl/lib directory in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH environnent variable

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/ssl/lib"`

Comment: On ubuntu, installing libssl1.0-dev before install python worked: `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev`

Answer (score 14):

same error for me. My case was a copied `virtenv` giving me this error on a new server. The default python was working.

I used

```
python2.7 -v -c "import hashlib" 2> output.txt
```

you should see something like this line below in your `output.txt`:

```
import hashlib # precompiled from hashlib.pyc
dlopen("/path/to/virtenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so", 2);

ldd /path/to/virtenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
...
   libssl.so.0.9.8 => not found
   libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => not found
...
```

So what I did is simply :

```
cp /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so /*path-to-virtenv*/manager/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use below command and check which libraries are missing,

```
ldd /path/to/Python-Library/_hashlibmodule.so
```

e.g

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/_hashlibmodule.so
```

If you get output like below, that means you are missing necessary openssl libraries

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd6f6a000)
    libssl.so.6 => not found
    libcrypto.so.6 => not found
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007ffb18b54000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffb18937000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffb185a2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffb1839e000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ffb1819b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffb17f16000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003e0a000000)
```

Comment: This example was a great help!  I used the following to find all missing SOs in a paticular environment: `ldd /opt/test/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/*.so | grep "not found"`

Comment: If SSL support wasn't compiled in you won't see these references - but their absence should tell you why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're using Solaris, but I've followed [these instructions](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/install-ruby-2-3-3-ubuntu.html) to install the old libssl1.0-dev and it worked on Ubuntu 20.04.

Edit file **/etc/apt/sources.list** and add this line to the end of it.

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
```

After that run:

```
sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
```

Finally,

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```