# static-python error on import hashlib

Tags: python, gcc, makefile, static-linking, hashlib

Using [static-python](https://github.com/bendmorris/static-python)

When I compile the binary (3.3.2 version), and run `./python`, if I import hashlib, I am receiving this error:

```
:akiva@akiva-ThinkPad-X230:~/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python$ ./python
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Aug  4 2015, 03:07:14) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/akiva/Programming/Projects/youtube-downloader/static/static-python/Lib/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
```

I used this command to compile:

```
make -f Static.make BUILTINS="_bisect  _codecs_cn  _codecs_hk  _codecs_iso2022  _codecs_jp  _codecs_kr  _codecs_tw  _collections  _csv  _ctypes  _ctypes_test  _elementtree  _functools  _hashlib  _heapq  _hotshot  _io  _json  _locale  _lsprof  _multibytecodec  _multiprocessing  _random  _socket   _struct  _testcapi  array  audioop  binascii  cmath  crypt   fcntl  future_builtins  grp  itertools  linuxaudiodev  math  mmap  nis  operator  ossaudiodev  parser  pyexpat  resource  select  spwd  syslog  termios  time  unicodedata  zlib ssl atexit"
```

The main reason for so many modules is to make sure it is compatible with youtube-dl 's script.

This question seems to have the solution here:

[Error importing hashlib with python 2.7 but not with 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399331/error-importing-hashlib-with-python-2-7-but-not-with-2-6)

But this solution is not applicable obviously to a static version of python. Is this the solution I am looking for, and is there a way to link openssl while running my make command?

Comment: My _guess_ is that you don't have the openssl developer package, libssl-dev, which contains the required headers. If that's the case, install that package & try compiling again. You may not need to change your compile command: with any luck `_hashlib` will handle that for you.

Comment: I have libssl-dev already installed, so I'll try to make it statically I guess~