# Issue while installing pip on linux

Tags: python-2.7, pip, suse

Facing issue While installing pip on `SuSe-release 12` on `python2.7.10`.
It used to work on `Suse-release 11`. But, throwing below errors on `Suse-release 12`.

On issuing `python get_pip.py` facing below errors.

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 19177, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "/tmp/tmpe4pKLZ/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpe4pKLZ/pip.zip/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpe4pKLZ/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpe4pKLZ/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpe4pKLZ/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

Above error is occurred on the `suse-linux 12`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error importing hashlib with python 2.7 but not with 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399331/error-importing-hashlib-with-python-2-7-but-not-with-2-6)

Comment: add suse tag && improve code output

Comment: Did not find /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so on my agent.
Can I copy it from the other agent which is Suse11. But, the issue is on suse12