# Developing on pycharm with a chroot environment?

Tags: linux, pycharm, chroot

I have an Arch Linux Machine inside which I have "containers" like `Centos` which I normally chroot and work upon from the command line. I setup Pycharm to work on a project that is inside this "container" The "container" was created using LXC, but I normally login using `chroot`.

There is a problem running the interactive debugger from `Pycharm` however.

The command that is run to start the interactive debugger from `Pycharm` is:

```
/usr/lib/lxc/centos/rootfs/home/virtual-environment/usr/bin/python /home/nishant/packages/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py

ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found
```

I was able to reproduce this problem without `Pycharm`.

If I `chroot` to that environment and then do `usr/bin/ python -v -c "import hashlib"` everything works.

If I execute `/usr/lib/lxc/centos/rootfs/home/virtual-environment/usr/bin/python` from my main system, the same error comes.

Fundamentally I think the problem is that I am executing the command in a wrong environment. I think `Pycharm` **should not** be executing this interpreter directly but instead in a `chroot` context.

1. Is it possible to achieve that using `Pycharm`?
2. In general, is it possible to execute a `chroot` command by not
   doing a `chroot`, like setting the LDD path differently or something
   like that?

Comment: Did you try googling the error message?

Comment: Yes I did that, it is not clear how do I apply that fix in this case. I am still trying to figure out. For example there is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399331/error-importing-hashlib-with-python-2-7-but-not-with-2-6. I think the problem is the same but the way to solve it in this case is what I am confused about.

Comment: Does your project depend on libssl or use a library which does? If so you need to be sure it is available from whatever directory is your `chroot`.

Comment: I thinking everything is there. Will check again. My fundamental question is, is it fine for Pycharm to run this `/usr/lib/lxc/centos/rootfs/home/virtual-environment/usr/bin/python` directly? How does it know that this is actually supposed to be run in a chrooted environment? Won't it otherwise pick up libraries from my host system?

Comment: python will have to simulate the chroot in some way. An alternative is to use the tool `virtualenv` instead of chroot.