# ImportError: cannot import name md5

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, openssl, homebrew, hashlib

Don't really know what's going on here, I need to deploy my flask app on elastic beanstalk but somehow changed the path and can't run python application.py anymore

```
[dotnet --info]
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.701
 Commit:    8cf7278aa1

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.14
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.14-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.701/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.12
  Commit:  ccea2e606d

[brew -v]
Homebrew 2.2.0
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 43ad0; last commit 2019-11-30)
```

I've already done these steps too :

```
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Still got this error:

```
File "/Users/ipchelsea/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 8, in <module>
    from hashlib import md5, sha1, sha256
ImportError: cannot import name md5
```

When I do [brew link --force openssl], I get below:

```
Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: openssl@1.1

ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 4, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/Users/ipchelsea/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Users/ipchelsea/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/Users/ipchelsea/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "/Users/ipchelsea/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .ssl_ import (
  File "/Users/ipchelsea/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 8, in <module>
    from hashlib import md5, sha1, sha256
ImportError: cannot import name md5
```

Answer (score 29):

I'm using macOS, fix this by `brew unlink openssl && brew reinstall python@2`

---

From comment, `python@2` is no longer available. This may work `brew unlink openssl && brew reinstall https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/86a44a0a552c673a05f11018459c9f5faae3becc/Formula/python@2.rb`

Comment: I am not sure `brew reinstall python@2` is still working as I think brew has now removed python2.

Comment: @oliversm is right. python@2 is no longer available. FormulaUnavailableError: No available formula with the name "/usr/local/opt/python@2/.brew/python@2.rb"

Answer (score 17):

I personally use and would recommend [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage Python versions. At first I was not sure how to fix this, and tried to re-install using `brew` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59438131). However, I then recalled that I had used `pyenv` to install and so I was able to fix my error with.

```
pyenv install -f 2.7.15
```

The `-f` option forces the installation of that version even if it already exists on your system. You would need to use `2.7.16` or whatever version you would like it to use.

The `python-build` that `pyenv` uses will use the `openssl` library from `brew` if it's available.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error on `Python 2.7.14`. Upgrading to `2.7.17` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using macOS and you can uninstall the python2 using `brew uninstall python@2`
After this you can install usin
`brew install {username}/python2/python@2.7.17`