# Error using pip command on MACOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

While running pip install command on terminal, I'm getting the following error :

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I tried reinstalling openssl via Homebrew but it didn't work. Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error importing hashlib with python 2.7 but not with 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399331/error-importing-hashlib-with-python-2-7-but-not-with-2-6)

Comment: @FlyingTeller tried the steps mentioned in the link, but still not working

Comment: What were you trying to install? Most libraries have dropped Python 2.7 support (including pip itself) which is bound to cause problems for you in the future as well.